# Hiding Spinner Items in Dropdown

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter

I have multiple spinners on one xml layout and each of them start with "...PLEASE SELECT". These are part of my database, not placed in by code. I would like to hide the "...PLEASE SELECT" when the dropdown of any of my spinners get selected.

I have read many questions regarding this topic and they do not work for me because I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate my spinners not an `ArrayAdapter`. If I was using an `ArrayAdapter` I could override the `getDropDownView()` method but because I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` I can't do this. If there are answers regarding my issue by using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and removing/hiding the first row of a spinner dropdown, I cannot find them.

How can I remove the first spinner item when the dropdown opens without using an `ArrayAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Spinner you should use EditText with a hint attribute.

For example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

In Java-code:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) return;

        // Показываем диалог
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
    });


public void onItemSelected(String itemName) {
    editText.setText(itemName);
}
```

And you should create a DialogFragment class MyDialog which displays a list of items and calls onItemSelected callback.

Comment: I would like to avoid changing most of my code if that is possible, but thank you for the suggestion.